# JSON string to JavaScript object error

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string:

```
{
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": "",
  "keyObj": {
    "key3": 300,
    "key4": 259200
  }
}
```

I'm trying to convert it to the javascript object with:

```
 JSON.parse(my_str.toString());
```

But i'm getting error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Why?

Thank you

Comment: How you define "my_str"?

Comment: Post all your code. Based on the posted info, [it works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/73dS2/).

Answer (score 2):

`my_str` seems to be already an object. So you just don't need to use `JSON.parse.

Because, probably,  `my_str.toString()` is equal to

```
[object Object]
 ^---------------- Unexpected token o
```

If you use `jQuery.ajax` remember that `jQuery` convert automatically JSON input data if it match coherent header

```
Content-type: application/jso
```

and/or if you set the `.ajax` option

```
dataType:'json'
```

if you're declaring manually `my_str =` then simply you should add quotes around the string (and put it into a single line or use some tip in order to do [multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript))

```
var my_str = '{"key1":"val1","key2":"","keyObj":{"key3":300,"key4":259200}}';
```

but doing manually has not much sense.